# ScoreLoop in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, scoreloop

Currently I am working on Social Game for iPhone. I want to integrate [ScoreLoop](http://www.scoreloop.com/) inside this games. If anybody know use of scoreloop. Please tell me How to use this ?

Thanks.

Comment: "SCORELOOP IS CLOSED"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check inside your Scoreloop SDK Folder (the one you downloaded), there will be a **Documentation** folder, where you can navigate to the ScoreloopCSE documentation **PDF file**, where all the steps are listed to get Scoreloop integrated into your application.

Refer to this link. I got on how to implement it from answer in this link:

[781 can not integrate scoreloop in cocos2d iphone](http://support.scoreloop.com/discussions/problems/781-can-not-integrate-scoreloop-in-cocos2d-iphone)

Hope this helps you.